Telecom cables for power transmission
Summary:  Can I use abandoned telecom wire bundles as a 3-phase neutral?
Our campus currently has underground AC cables supplying 2 legs of 3 phase wye power to a remote (50 ft away) building.  There are 3 3/0 cables in the conduit.  We want to upgrade the remote panel to provide 200A 3phase inside that building.  However, we need a fourth cable to do this.
There are some abandoned copper wire bundles in another nearby conduit that also lead to the remote building.  First bundle has 32 wires of 0.48mm diameter.  Second bundle has 50 wires of .45mm diameter.
We really don't want to dig a trench to add new conduit if we can avoid it.  We tried pulling the telecom wires out (using a puller machine) but they won't budge.  Is there any feasible way to use the two telecom bundles in place as a fourth wire for the 3-phase wye?
Any other non-trenching ideas to get the fourth wire over to that building?

You have given no location, but I don't think any civilised country's regulations would allow that. 3-phase Delta/Star (Wye) transformer with neutralising link would solve the problem in an approved manner.

Location is Indiana USA.  We did get a quote to use the transformer solution, $45k was too steep for the budget.

This question and answers are educational for many people!  Please do not punish the person asking!

You can find suitable transformers for much less than US 45k if you search.  Especially check with suppliers who handle used equipment.

Your telecom wiring almost certainly doesn't have the insulation necessary to carry 'mains' voltage levels and even if is does, the NEC doesn't permit paralleling conductors outside of some specific circumstances (and this is not one of those).

It's fair to assume that any telecoms cable caries telecom-level current and voltage, and is buried in telecom conduits with telecom labeling at telecom depths. Putting power levels in a telecom cable is an invitation to accidental fatality. Unfortunately, it's like routing a freeway through an elementary school playground because "that's the only good option".

Do the 3/0 cables move? If the conduit is not too full, you could add a neutral there. 50 ft is not very far, and they have gotten the wires there somehow so it seems likely you could pull new ones.

We've not yet investigated whether the 3/0 lines are movable, they are still in service.  This is worth checking out, if we can get it out and add a fourth wire there.  But it's a very old metal conduit and I fear it may be collapsed like the telecom conduit.

Is the conduit metal?  Carrying neutral current outside the conduit could lead to inductive heating of the conduit.

I am quite certain that (1) this is not allowed by regulations and (2) it is inadvisable.
I have seen stuff done at a university which was probably strictly speaking not a good idea- but this way past the line.

The total cross-sectional area is really small for a 200A supply.  In the worst case on the 3P+N supply, 200A could flow in the neutral.
[32 (0.24)² π] + [50 (0.225)² π] = 13.7mm²
The voltage rating of the cable insulation may be too low.  Many data cables are only rated for 80V.

When you tried to pull the telecom wires out, did you try one wire at a time, or the entire bundle?
I suspect if you tried just a single wire, they were somewhat tangled within the conduit and therefore essentially stuck into a single big bundle (they may have actually been taped together at intervals to aid in pulling them in the first place). If you haven't already tried it, try pulling the entire bundle out all at once.
Another option is to use an air compressor/vacuum and some light oil to lubricate the wires so they would slide out easier using the puller on the entire bundle of wires. The lubricant can be easily cleaned out after the conduit is empty.

Tried pulling them out as both bundles together.  There are two jacketed insulated bundles.  We used a tugging machine, and it ripped off both bundles about 6 inches just outside the conduit.  I would love to be able to send a tiny spy cam down the tube to see if it is really collapsed.
